# Zend Framework : gzip and cache

Tags: php, zend-framework, caching, gzip

I have lots of javascript, stylesheets and images in my `Zend Framework` application.

I want to cache and compress them so that there will be a little load to my server

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may want to use this: [Cache JS & CSS Zend Framework](https://github.com/bubba-h57/zf-helpers)

Ref: [Minify](http://code.google.com/p/minify/)

Comment: I'm having a hardtime setting it up :/

Answer (score 2):

You may want to investigate the PHP library "Assetic": https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic

This library will allow you to bundle, compress, and minify your javascript and css resources.  The library also offers a few ways to cache the bundled versions of your assets.

You may want to also consider moving your assets to a third party content delivery network, like Amazon CloudFront (http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/).

(Assetic will help you load your bundled resources to an S3 bucket, as well.)